# read/watch problem in a flutter provider list

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have an empty, dynamic list that accepts tiles in a change notifier and when the user makes selections in another part of the app, these selections are added to the list as tiles that show the name they selected as well as how many times they selected it. these tiles are then displayed elsewhere in the app. This I have working. and the tiles are being added to the list.

my problem is that when a name is selected, I only want the tile to be added to the list once and then the number of times selected counter to increase with each press.

here is my code to do this:

```
if (context.read<Selections>().timesSelected == 0) {
      context.read<Selections>().selectedList.add(
            NamesTile(
                text:
                    context.read<Selections>().namesList[0],
                number:
                    '${context.read<Selections>().timesSelected}'),
          );
```

With this code the tile is being added and context.read().timesSelected (this counter is increased when the name is selected) increases to 1 which is what I want it to do. the problem then is when it is selected again, the context.read().timesSelected doesn't increase.

I believe this is because in the number value of the NamesTile widget, I can only set context.read().timesSelected to be read. when I set it to watch, I get an error saying:

Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.

is it possible for a provider to both read and watch at the same time? and if so, how would i get this to increase in the tile?